# Error:Execution failed for task : Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

this error appeared since it was updated to android 3.0

build.gradle (**Module:app**):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.example.samue.radiostatus"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }




}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.github.snowdream.android:smartimageview:0.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    implementation files('libs/android-smart-image-view-1.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
    implementation files('libs/additionnal (1).jar')
    implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar')
    implementation files('libs/javamail-mailapi-1.4.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/javamail-smtp-1.4.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail (1).jar')

}
```

build gradle (**project**):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have duplicates dependencies. You can't mix the same dependency from repositories and from local jar files. So, you need to clean up your **app** `build.gradle`. And also, don't use **`+`** for dependencies. Use exact version of dependencies. This is because you can't specify a problem for a library if you don't know its exact version.

You need to clean up your build.gradle to something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.github.snowdream.android:smartimageview:0.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'

    implementation files('libs/httpmime-4.3.jar')
    //implementation files('libs/android-smart-image-view-1.0.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
    implementation files('libs/additionnal (1).jar')
    //implementation files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.9.jar')
    implementation files('libs/javamail-mailapi-1.4.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/javamail-smtp-1.4.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail (1).jar')

}
```